# Open Subtitles API user_id uploads search returning 'Not enough parameters'

Tags: rest, video-subtitles

I'm trying to request the Opensubtitles uploads of a given `user_id` but it's returning:

> {'errors': ['Not enough parameters'], 'status': 400}

The request body is:

```
headers = {
  'Api-Key': <API_KEY>,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'User-Agent': 'MyApp v1.2.3',
}

params = {
  'user_id': '8411358',
}

r = requests.get('https://api.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/subtitles', params=params, headers=headers)
```

According to the [API documentation](https://opensubtitles.stoplight.io/docs/opensubtitles-api/a172317bd5ccc-search-for-subtitles#Query-Parameters) the `user_id` parameter should be used alone though:

```
user_id integer 
To be used alone - for user uploads listing
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just got a message from a dev: "just a typo, it should be `uploader_id`"